# Aligning inline-block elements horizontally

Tags: html, css, margin, display

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. I try to get the divs to be displayed as inline-block and the remaining
   width (spaces) should be distributed evenly around the divs (as in
   with margin: auto).
2. I try to get the divs TOP and not the BOTTOM border to be align to each
   other, leaving the specified margin top and bottom for any div below
   or above each other based on it's height. Just like the image
   attached

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Jwl.jpg)

[Example: [see codepen](https://codepen.io/Keleoswilliam/pen/VwZjaNv) ]
css:

```css
#container {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#container div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* must be inline-block, not BLOCK */
  margin: 5px auto;
  /* AUTO works fine if set to display:block; and not display:inline-block; */
  width: 120px;
  /* the longer the item name, the width should auto expand to fit */
  margin: 2px auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three </li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three </li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>Item six </li>
      <li>Item seven</li>
      <li>Item eight</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three </li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three </li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>Item six </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three </li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: You should also show your HTML so that people can easily test and tinker with your code

Comment: Thanks Steph. This actually my first post and I appreciate appreciate your tips.  I included it in via codepen instead. Will embed it directly next time

Comment: vertical-align and text-align seems to be what you look for. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KKPMMrL (it's been already said, yep) , flex can do this too without involving inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inline-block items, you can use `vertical-align: top` to align siblings to the top.

For evenly spaced widths, you can define a width value percentage within `#container div` or tell the parent `#container` to be `display: flex` (which will also align the items to the top).

```css
#container{
  min-height: 200px;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
#container div {
  border:2px solid red;
  padding:10px; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin:5px auto;
  width:120px;
  margin:2px auto;
  vertical-align: top; /* use on inline-items */
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>Item three </li>
            <li>Item four</li>
            <li>Item five</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>Item three </li>
            <li>Item four</li>
            <li>Item five</li>
            <li>Item six </li>
            <li>Item seven</li>
            <li>Item eight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>Item three </li>
            <li>Item four</li>
            <li>Item five</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>Item three </li>
            <li>Item four</li>
            <li>Item five</li>
            <li>Item six </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>Item three </li>
            <li>Item four</li>
            <li>Item five</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: So I found this somehow perfect solution by adding the following codes to the container (parent): 
      ```css
    display:flex;
                justify-content:center;
                flex-flow:row wrap;
               ```

Answer (score 1):

Margin:0 auto property is for block level elements in case you want to center any block level element inside a block level element.

---

1:) The block level element that you want to center should have a defined height otherwise **Margin:0 auto** won't work.

---

2:) You can center inline-block or inline elements using text-align: center in parent container as parent treat child element like text.

In your case you have defined the #container div as inline-block so

> margin: user-defined auto;

won't work as it is no more block level element Although you have defined a width but it won't work. Try to use **text-align** property in parent.Hope the question is answered

Comment: Setting ```:center;``` on the parent (container) not just centralize the inner div but all content of the div.

Comment: When you set the :center to parent all of it childs will be treated as text and will be centered.It won't center the inside content of child div

Comment: This seem to answer my first question relatively.  Can anyone help me with the second question, so that the divs will look like the image in my question? Thanks